# KMeans clustering for Image Data

Tags: python, k-means, clustering

I am trying to cluster the sample of Imagenet Dataset using K-Means clustering.

In this approach, I have used the below 2 approaches to get the optimal number of clusters.

1. Elbow method 
    [image] From the Graph it seems like the best number of clusters is from 6 to 10.
2. Silhouette score

```
Cluster : 2 | Silhouette score : 0.036273542791604996
Cluster : 3 | Silhouette score : -0.00300691369920969
Cluster : 4 | Silhouette score : 0.0025101888459175825
Cluster : 5 | Silhouette score : -0.005924953147768974
Cluster : 6 | Silhouette score : -0.00808520708233118
Cluster : 7 | Silhouette score : -0.006091121584177017
Cluster : 8 | Silhouette score : -0.00549863139167428
Cluster : 9 | Silhouette score : -0.014739749021828175
Cluster : 10 | Silhouette score : -0.021131910383701324
Cluster : 11 | Silhouette score : -0.04057755321264267
Cluster : 12 | Silhouette score : -0.012825582176446915
Cluster : 13 | Silhouette score : -0.012340431101620197
Cluster : 14 | Silhouette score : -0.032936643809080124
Cluster : 15 | Silhouette score : -0.04154697805643082
Cluster : 16 | Silhouette score : -0.04323640838265419
```

Where as in Silhouette analysis it looks like only for cluster 4 it is showing better value. Rest of the clusters are seems like samples are wrongly assigned to wrong clusters.

In such cases, which metric needs to be considered?

Updates: 
I have reduced the dimension of the features using PCA. Below are the updated graphs for Elbow and Silhouette analysis. However I do not see any improvement in the clustering. As per Silhouette the samples are not being assigned to the closest cluster.

**Elbow** 
[image]

**Silhouette** 
[image]

Updating the question with latest graphs, VGGNet has been replaced by Resnet50

[image]

Code snippet:

```
        for i in range(lower_range, upper_range):
            # For Elbow curve
            kmeans_cluster = KMeans(n_clusters = i)
            kmeans_cluster_fit = kmeans_cluster.fit(features_list_np)
            loss = kmeans_cluster_fit.inertia_
            error.append(kmeans_cluster_fit.inertia_)

            # For Silhoutte analysis
            preds = kmeans_cluster.fit_predict(features_list_np)
            score = silhouette_score(features_list_np, preds)
            score_list.append(score)

            sample_score = silhouette_samples(features_list_np, preds)
            sample_score_list.append(sample_score)

            print("Cluster : {} | Loss : {} | Silhoutte Score : {}".format(i, loss, score))

            zero_samples = 0
            positive_samples = 0
            negative_samples = 0

            for each_sample in sample_score:
                if each_sample == 0:
                    zero_samples += 1
                if each_sample > 0:
                    positive_samples += 1
                if each_sample < 0:
                    negative_samples += 1

            print("Cluster : {} | Silhouette sample distribution - Zero : {} | Positive : {} | Negative : {}".format(i, zero_samples, positive_samples, negative_samples))

            zero_list.append(zero_samples)
            pos_list.append(positive_samples)
            neg_list.append(negative_samples)
```

Also should the importance should be given to Silhouette Score or the Silhouette Samples. Because in some of the cases, Silhouette score is less but the number of samples having positive values are more.

Thank you, 
 
KK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Neither, there is not enough discriminatory information in data (yet)**

Dont squeeze the data until it tells you the truth. You can change the metric (malahobian distance for example) and the algo but you cant expect it to show miracles.

Using elbow method, as you increase the number of clusters it will always become more homogenous. You dont have a "kink" indicating optimal clustering number.

And with Silhouete (be careful those are averaged Silhoute score per cluster, in other words for k=4 you have 4 scores indicating wether points are lying inside/border/should- be-other-cluster that are averaged) you get that all of the points (in average) lie on the border of the clusters, without clear distinction of the clusters (thats what 0 means).

**Advice** Find better quantitative representation of data, new feature, reduce noise etc...

Comment: As mentioned in the below comment, I use pre-trained ```VGGNet``` to extract the features and using it for clustering.

Answer (score 3):

A Silhouette score close to 0 says the clustering is not reliable.

And the Elbow method is *crap*. On random data the curve would drop roughly like 1/(k-1); so it's largely undefined wh em they is an elbow and when not. In your case, what troubles me most is that the values appear to stagnate to a cake *much* larger than zero. Maybe there is an error in your clustering code? Your results look like random to me.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using samples of class from the Imagenet dataset and using it to cluster the images. 
Images are passed through pre-trained ```VGGNet``` to extract the features. And ```K-Means``` cluster is applied on the extracted features.

Comment: Negative Silhouette on average *should* be impossible with k-means (a few points may have negative values, but the majority must be assigned to the nearest cluster). You really should debug carefully, the result seems to be corrupted.

Comment: There maybe possibility that data samples are overlapped with each other ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That would still give a Silhouette of at least 0. Negative values mean that objects are, on average, *not* assigned to their nearest center!

Comment: Thanks for making me understanding. I am trying to figure what I am doing wrong. 
I even tried with PCA, however it did not performance of the model.

Comment: Probably because the error in your code is still there?

Comment: I replaced the VGGnet with Resnet50. Now I am able to get positive values for the Silhouette score.

Comment: Bad input data is not even enough to explain negative average silhouette. K-means assigns points to the nearest center; hence the distance to the average cluster member must usually be smaller than to members of the next cluster. Similarly, the elbow plot must converge to 0 as you increase k. That is not depending on the input data to the k-means clustering. At most, your clustering may have been stopped too early (set tolerance to 0, try more iterations).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try setting tolerance to zero and check if it improves the performance. However as I mentioned in the previous comment, the performance had been significantly improved by changing the feature extraction to ```Resnet50```. Maybe in case of ```VGGnet``` the cluster labels were assigning wrongly ?

Comment: How would it assign cluster labels "wrongly" ever, unless you shuffle your data/labels between clustering and computing the silhouette, which would be a coding error in your code. P.S. only Silhouette values > 0.5 are considered good. Small positives do not indicate good k. Maybe add the new plots.

Comment: I am not shuffling the datapoints between clustering and computing silhouette. Even I am wondering how Kmeans would assign the cluster wrongly. I have updated the question with the latest silhouette graph. I have skipped Elbow curve.

Comment: I'm not saying you intentionally shuffle. But there clearly is something wrong in your code. Because these values are only as good as *random* labelings. Whatever you are doing, there is a BUG somewhere. Either in your code, or in the library that you are using. More likely the first.

Comment: Thank you. I have just updated the code snippet. I am sorry, I am not able to understand what is wrong here.

Comment: No obvious error in your code, except that you run kmeans twice; but that shouldn't cause these problems. Maybe its the tolerance default, too few iterations, or a bug in the kmeans that you use.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I change the iterations ? Looks like the default value for tolerance is ```tol float, default=1e-4```. Should I set this to 0 ?

Comment: I have updated the question with a doubt on Silhouette score and Silhouette samples.